# Remove the tag <a> but not content

Tags: php, dom, domdocument

I'm trying to get all links from a page and remove them, except the contents of those links. The code not works 100%, because some lins are removed and others not.

I'm using PHP and DOMDocument.

```
   $dom = new DOMDocument();
   $dom->encoding = 'utf-8';
   $dom->loadHTML(utf8_decode($text));

   $links = $dom->getELementsByTagName('a');

   foreach($links as $link)
   {
       $link->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($link->textContent), $link);//I've tried this way but not work.

       //And I've tried other way below:
       /*$sibling = $link->firstChild;
       do {
          $next = $sibling->nextSibling;
          $link->parentNode->insertBefore($sibling, $link);
       } while ($sibling = $next);
       $link->parentNode->removeChild($link);*/
   }
   return $dom->saveHTML();
```

For example, we have three links:

```
<p>Page</p>
<a href="http://domain/page/pag.php?id_pag=1481">Page1</a>
<a href="http://domain/page/pag.php?id_pag=1482">Page2</a>
<a href="http://domain/page/pag.php?id_pag=1483">Page3</a>
<p>Test</p>
```

The result is:

```
<p>Page</p>
Page1
<a href="http://domain/page/pag.php?id_pag=1482">Page2</a>
Page3
<p>Test</p>
```

I want all links removed (not content).
Any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: I think it's because `$links` is a live node list. So when you replace one of the anchors, the list is adjusted and the next iteration skips an element.

Comment: Make a copy of `$links` as an ordinary array, and loop over that instead.

Comment: Can you give me a example? Thank you!

Comment: If I copy $links to array, how can I remove and update de page content? Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a copy of `$links` as an ordinary array, because the object that `getElementsByTagName()` returns is a "live" `NodeList` -- it changes as you modify the DOM, and this causes the `foreach` loop to skip elements (it's the same problem as trying to delete elements from an array while you're looping over it).

```
$links_array = [];
foreach ($links as $l) {
    $links_array[] = $l;
}
foreach($links_array as $link)
{
   $link->parentNode->replaceChild(new DOMText($link->textContent), $link);
}
```

Comment: Now I understood! This solved the problem. Thank you!